# How to loop-click a button through developer console?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this.

I wrote this code

```
var chars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j,","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
        var value = chars[i] + chars[j];
        document.getElementById("text").value = value;
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").click();
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

The page reloads if the click happens.

I want the loop to wait until the page is fully loaded and they continue with next iteration. Right now it prints all the value and page reloads only once.

I'm running this in Safari developer console.

Comment: This would be a job for an extension.

Comment: The web console usually runs code inside the page. When the page reloads, all old code is killed. So you need to run code outside the page. You can do that with a browser console or with an extension. Alternatively, you can use an userscript which will automatically each time the page is loaded.

Comment: @Oriol What's a browser console?

Comment: @RaghavSharma It's a console that has more privileges than the web console. Not sure if Safari has something like that. On Firefox, Ctrl+Shift+K is web console and Ctrl+Shift+J is browser console. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console).

Comment: @Oriol I guess you can't directly execute the same JS code you would execute in web console? Because it gave me `document.getElementById(...) is null`. I'll read that guide.